# Tooltip popup with dynamic information

Tags: java, css, html, jsp, tooltip

What I am trying to do is when you hover over a name, show a tooltip popup with details of that name.

I did the following but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work. No tooltip shows up. When you hover over a name it calls a function and does an AJAX request and we get back details as string. I have verified that the function works fine and returns string.

I just can't seem to be able to get that returned string into the tooltip popup. I am testing this on IE8

Javascript Function:

```
function showDetails(name){
    var xmlHttpRequest; 
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP>");
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "showStopsInfoPopup.do?name="+name, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}
```

CSS

```
#tooltip { position: relative; }
    #tooltip a{text-decoration: none;}
    #tooltip a span { display: none; color: #FFFFFF; }
    #tooltip a:HOVER span { display: block; position: absolute; 
                             width: 200px; background-color: #aaa; 
                             height: 50px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px; }
```

JSP page:

```
<tr id="tooltip">
    <td onmouseover="showDetails('${name}')">
        <a href="#"><c:out value="${name}"><span id="details"></span></c:out></a> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Only the relevant part of my view source page(generated html): "span" tag inside the "a" tag is missing!!

```
<tr id="tooltip">               
    <td onmouseover ="showDetails('NRT')"><a href="#">NRT</a> </td> 
</tr>    
.
.
.
...  
<span id="details">*****************</span>
```

Comment: xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
    } - does it work?  maybe its not showing because its not returning a valid response?

Comment: yes it works.. I did onClick() instead of onmouseover and displayed the data at the bottom of the page instead of a tooltip and it got displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are generating your data that's being displayed dynamically and that you have more than one row.

If so, then all the span tag in your table will have the same id("details"). You have to be able to distinguish between two rows.

What you can do is add a number to the id and increment the number as you go to the next row, so that each span tag has unique id.

```
<a href="#"><c:out value="${name}"><span id="details${index}"></span></c:out></a>
```

be sure to pass the index as an argument to your javascript function and make the following change.

```
function showDetails(name, index){
..
...
document.getElementById("stopsInfo"+index).innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
.
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you view the source and show us the HTML generated. I tried this and it seems to work okay when just doing a quick test.

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the view source at the end of my question. For some reason, the span tag that I have inside the <a> tag is not there when I do the view source.

Comment: Try getting rid of the <c:out value... tags around your span tag and see if it works now. Then at least we know it works and your span tag is showing up in the view source.